# The Warded/Painted Man ending

Tags: the-painted-man

I know this is a strange question, but how does [*The Warded Man*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warded_Man) (also published as *The Painted Man*) by [Peter V. Brett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_V._Brett) end?

I read the translation which ended when Arlen finds the spear and discovers that it can hurt demons. I returned to the series in English and I found some discontinuity. After quick checking I found that the translator 'forgot' to include part of the story and what I though was open ending was not entirely and ending - I missed everything after finding the spear.

1. Did I miss a large portion of the book?
2. If not - what did I miss (if yes, I will just by a 'proper' version - sigh... I know much can be lost in translation but I didn't imagine that it could include an entire plotline).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you read the Polish translation, which was split into two books. You only read half the story. The second half is available. Hope you like it!

Comment: I loved the first part. I'm not living in Poland (I grow up there and I bought the book while visiting my Parents) and I doubt I will find the II part in UK. I will simply buy the English version before returning to Desert Spear. Thank you for both reply and book - one of the best I read recently.